# react bootstrap: what does the react bootstrap site use for the docs sidebar?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I am looking at the site https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#navigation and I cannot see how they managed to get the boostrap docs sidebar to work. When viewing the source, I can see that the class is `bs-docs-sidenav`

But there is not a straightforward component, I can only google information about how to do it with raw bootstrap. I was thinking of distributing a component that would use react bootstrap to make it, but I wanted to make sure there is not an easier way first that I am missing...

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the React dev tools (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en) to see that it's not a normal bootstrap component that you can just import, but a custom one that they've written for that purpose. So unfortunately you'll have to re-write it from scratch if you want similar functionality.